# Display an image that is stored outside the project with primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I upload an image in my local disk  **(image.path=C:/images/)** like this :

```
InputStream input = file.getInputstream();



InputStream appProperties = MyBean.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties");
                Properties prop = new Properties();
                prop.load(appProperties);


                String path = prop.getProperty("image.path");
                Path newPath = new File(path+"", agence.getId()+".png" ).toPath();
```

and now I want to display it in my view on **datalist with graphicImage**?

Thank you ALL,